# Performance issue with Radeon HD 7600G on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, asus, radeon, performance

I have an U38N Asus laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed on it. It seems that I have a problem with the performance when I see a HD video on YouTube or VLC. I also have problems of lack with the animations and transitions of the system (GNOME).

These are my hardware specs:

```
*-display
     description: VGA compatible controller
     product: Trinity [Radeon HD 7600G]
     vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
     physical id: 1
     bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
     version: 00
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
     configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
     resources: irq:35 memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:c0000-dffff
```